# Image+TextView+radiobutton in spinner

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, imageview, android-arrayadapter

First, I want to imitate the effect like "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item"

which is TextView+radiobutton

but either the getView() or getDropDownView only cares about one row at a time, while the whole radiobuttons in spinner is like one RadioGroup, and when dropdown view is opened, the radiobutton with which item is selected before must be checked.

so how can I imitate the layout like simple_spinner_dropdown_item?

Second, I want to add different ImageView in each row, so I can't just use the default simple_spinner_dropdown_item, I must redefine the ArrayAdapter.

So, is there a best way to get through these?

I like the layout in simple_spinner_dropdown_item, but I also want to add ImageView...

Please give me any clue at all

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

extend the adapter. Override getView() and change the view that is returned to what you are after.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement a more generic adapter without overriding the arrayadapter you can look at the post at http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/using-custom-layouts-for-spinner-or-listview-entries-in-android/ its using the baseadapter which can be modified as desired.